# joomla 1.5 mariadb 10

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, mariadb

I have a cpanel server which I tried to upgrade the MySQL to MariaDB 10, now everything works except many Joomla 1.5 websites which were using unicode languages are now displaying question mark instead of every character:

I have to clarify things more: The sites were displaying correctly with MySQL 5.5 before upgrade, and the data is intact in the database so when I copy the site into another MariaDB 5.6 server, it displays correctly.

I tried :
 /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf

```
[mysqld]
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
```

and /etc/my.cnf.d/mysql-clients.cnf

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```

In joomla system information I get:

> Database Collation:   N/A (mySQL < 4.1.2)

No luck

Comment: This seems a question more suitable for superuser or serverfault. However, I guess you are having some issue regarding character sets. You could contact the mariadb people, they are willing to give good support. If you get a solution, post it here! :)

Comment: I disagree with asking in every forum because it's urgent. I think you should have asked here before doing the upgrade. No, unfortunately I don't have any solution.

Comment: Search this forum for `utf8 question marks user:1766831`

Comment: @Rick , I have searched ,no luck, it seems a mariadb configuration/driver issue which seems should have been discussed before

Comment: @jotadepicas, Thank you very much for your help, it doesn't seem a server issue, the problem is: joomla 1.5 is not working with default Mariadb 10 , Database& collation is unicode (utf8_general_ci) , anyway I have been directed here from mariadb community page:[link] (https://mariadb.com/resources/community-tools)  (Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers including MariaDB users. Its easy and free.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I asked in joomla and mariadb  forum and no answers so I inspected and found the issue, I post here so if anyone needs to benefit the mariadb 10 for even older and non-supported versions can use this quick fix.

hope it helps

in

```
libraries/joomla/database/database/mysql.php
```

or (depending on your setting)

```
libraries/joomla/database/database/mysqli.php
```

comment the line 186

```
return ($verParts[0] == 5 || ($verParts[0] == 4 && $verParts[1] == 1 && (int)$verParts[2] >= 2));
```

and add this instead(assuming these days you'll have unicode supported database:

```
return (1);
```

the code looks like:

```
function hasUTF()
{
    $verParts = explode( '.', $this->getVersion() );
//  return ($verParts[0] == 5 || ($verParts[0] == 4 && $verParts[1] == 1 && (int)$verParts[2] >= 2));
return (1);
}
```

Best

Comment: When returning values, you do not need to wrap them in parentheses. The line `return 1;` or `return true;` is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
```

will probably show you what is wrong.

Question marks come from this:

- The client has a valid character, and
- The `SET NAMES` agrees with the encoding that the client has, but
- The target column's `CHARACTER SET` does not include the intended character.